# Possible to get api call value from DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, api

Is it possible to get a "value" from inside a span ?

given the following situation:

```
<div>
<span id="return-from-api">436</span>
</div>
```

is it possible, (as this value is returned from a Api call), to grab this value to use it as a value somewhere else in the site ? say for example i have my api call in apicall.js and manipulate the DOM in index.html giving the about situation..but i want to read that value in cart.js for something else ?

it has to be pure javascript/ Html and no JQuery :)

I hope my question made sense ! thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to read the contents of an HTML element? If so, did you try searching for the answer first?

Comment: tried searching for the answer but was difficult when i didnt know how to explai nit hehe but it seems you nailed it, will try out this method :)

Comment: `document.getElementById('return-from-api').innerText`

Answer (score 1):

The MDN documentation is your friend : [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
document.querySelector('#return-from-api').innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using "document.getElementById()" ?